# Autofac and ASP .Net MVC 4 Web API

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, autofac, sharepoint-2013

I am using **Autofac** for IoC in my ASP .Net MVC 4 project. Autofac is having some trouble initializing the repository and passing it to the **API Controller**.

I am sure I am missing something in my configuration.

Here is the error I get when I navigate to: `https://localhost:44305/api/integration`

```
<Error>
    <Message>An error has occurred.</Message>
    <ExceptionMessage>
        None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' 
        on type 'EL.Web.Controllers.API.IntegrationController' can be invoked with 
        the available services and parameters: Cannot resolve parameter 
        'EL.Web.Infrastructure.IRepository`1[EL.Web.Models.Integration] repository' of 
        constructor 'Void .ctor(EL.Web.Infrastructure.IRepository`1[EL.Web.Models.Integration])'.
    </ExceptionMessage>
    <ExceptionType>Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException</ExceptionType>
    <StackTrace>
        at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters) 
        at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters) 
        at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute() 
        at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) 
        at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) 
        at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) 
        at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.ResolveComponent(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters) 
        at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) 
        at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptionalService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters) 
        at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType, IEnumerable`1 parameters) 
        at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveOptional(IComponentContext context, Type serviceType) 
        at Autofac.Integration.WebApi.AutofacWebApiDependencyScope.GetService(Type serviceType) 
        at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator) 
        at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
    </StackTrace>
</Error>
```

Here are some relevant bits of code:

**IoC Bootstrapper:**

```
public static class Bootstrapper
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        builder.Register(x => new SharePointContext(HttpContext.Current.Request)).As<ISharePointContext>().SingleInstance();
        builder.RegisterType<SharePointRepository<IEntity>>().As<IRepository<IEntity>>();
        builder.RegisterType<SharePointContextFilter>().SingleInstance();

        builder.RegisterFilterProvider();

        IContainer container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

        var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
    }
}
```

**IRepository:**

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
    void Add(T entity);

    void Delete(int id);

    IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null);

    void Update(int id, T entity);
}
```

**SharePointRepository:**

```
internal class SharePointRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : IEntity
{
    private readonly ISharePointContext _context;
    private readonly string _listName;

    internal SharePointRepository(ISharePointContext context)
    {
        _context = context;

        object[] attributes = typeof (T).GetCustomAttributes(typeof (SharePointListAttribute), false);

        if (!attributes.Any())
        {
            throw new Exception("No associated SharePoint list defined for " + typeof (T));
        }

        _listName = ((SharePointListAttribute) attributes[0]).ListName;
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Update(int id, T entity)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**IntegrationController:**

```
public class IntegrationController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IRepository<Integration> _repository;

    public IntegrationController(IRepository<Integration> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public void Delete(Guid integrationId)
    {
        _repository.Delete(Get(integrationId).Id);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Integration> Get()
    {
        return _repository.Find();
    }

    public Integration Get(Guid integrationId)
    {
        return _repository.Find(i => i.IntegrationId == integrationId).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public void Post([FromBody] Integration integration)
    {
        _repository.Add(integration);
    }

    public void Put(Guid integrationId, [FromBody] Integration integration)
    {
        _repository.Update(Get(integrationId).Id, integration);
    }
}
```

**IEntity:**

```
internal interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; }
}
```

**Entity:**

```
public abstract class Entity : IEntity
{
    protected Entity(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }

    public int Id { get; private set; }
}
```

**Integration:**

```
[SharePointList("Integrations")]
public class Integration : Entity
{
    public Integration(int id) : base(id)
    {
    }

    public string ApiUrl { get; set; }

    public bool DeletionAllowed { get; set; }

    public Guid IntegrationId { get; set; }

    public string Key { get; set; }

    public string List { get; set; }

    public bool OutgoingAllowed { get; set; }

    public string RemoteWeb { get; set; }

    public string Web { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: define "having some trouble".  Did you read this? http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have registered your `IRepository` wrong. With the line:

```
builder.RegisterType<SharePointRepository<IEntity>>().As<IRepository<IEntity>>();
```

You told Autofac that whenever somebody will request an `IRepository<IEntity>` give them a `SharePointRepository<IEntity>`, but you are requesting a concrete `IRepository<Integration>` so you get an exception.

What you need is the [open generic registration feature of Autofac](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/OpenGenerics). So change your registration to:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(SharePointRepository<>))
       .As(typeof(IRepository<>));
```

It will work as you would expect you when you ask for a `IRepository<Integration>` it will give a `SharePointRepository<Integration>`.

You also have a second unrelated problem: your `SharePointRepository` has only an `internal` constructor.

Autofac by default only looks for `public` constructors so you either change your constructor and class to `public` or you need to tell to Autofac to look for NonPublic constructors with the `FindConstructorsWith` method:

```
builder
    .RegisterType<SharePointRepository<IEntity>>()
    .FindConstructorsWith(
       new DefaultConstructorFinder(type => 
          type.GetConstructors(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))) 
    .As<IRepository<IEntity>>();
```

Comment: this did help me resolve the issue I was initially having. But, now I get a new error: `No constructors on type 'EL.Web.Infrastructure.SharePointRepository`1[EL.Web.Models.Integration]' can be found with the constructor finder 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder'`.

I am a little confused here. I have already defined to use `SharePointContext` as `ISharePointContext` -- and this is the only parameter the repository needs.

Comment: Your problem is that your `SharePointRepository1` class only has internal constructors. See my updated answer.